# Does somebody know where to find original paper of Lehmann, Symanzik and Zimmerman (LSZ) translated in English?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, specific-reference, correlation-functions, s-matrix-theory

Does anybody know where to find the original paper about [LSZ reduction formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LSZ_reduction_formula) translated in english? Unfortunately, I've only found the original German article:

> H. Lehmann, K. Symanzik, and W. Zimmerman, "Zur Formulierung quantisierter Feldtheorien," Nuovo Cimento 1(1), 205 (1955).

Answer (score 3):

You can find the translation in *Dispersion Relations and the Abstract Approach to Field Theory, edited by Lewis Klein (1961)* on page 15.